# Read contents from SslStream

Tags: c#, ssl, imap

I have an application using which I execute IMAP commands using:

- `TcpClient` to connect to the IMAP server
- `SslStream` to write and read commands

Problem:

- Cannot read the complete ouput content from the stream
- `while` loop on the `SslStream.Read` seems not to work
- `StreamReader.ReadLine`, `ReadToEnd`, `Read` methods do not work

Sample code:

```
while ((l = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    output.AppendLine(l);
}
```

This code snippet would read 1 to 2 lines and hang in `reader.Readline()`.

Workaround I tried with setting the `ReadTimeout` property:

```
try
{
    _output=new byte[_tcpclient.ReceiveBufferSize];
    _sslstream.Read(_output, 0, _output.Length);
    textBox1.Text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(_output);
}
catch (IOException ex)
{
    textBox1.Text ="ERROR !! " + ex.Message;                
}
```

Help:

- How can I read the complete output of a command from the stream?

Note: I do not want to use any third party libraries.

Comment: What makes you think you can do a better job than third-party libraries?

Comment: @SLaks: programming isn't nessecarily about doing a better job.  Sometimes you just have to try and see what you can do.. what is possible.

Comment: @Boo: True.  Also, i have yet to see a good .Net IMAP client.  I started writing one myself, but got side-tracked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The TCP stream cannot know whether the current response has finished.  All it knows is whether it has just received data on the wire; it cannot know whether the next packet is going to come right now (a multi-packet response) or whether it will come much later (if the response is finished).

Instead, you need to predict when you'll get more data; you should keep reading until you receive a tagged completion response, as documented in the IMAP protocol.

However, IMAP seems to be intended to be read continuously on a background thread, since the server can send you information at any time.  Therefore, you probably ought to have a separate thread which is always in `ReadLine()`.